# How To Refresh/Clear the DistributedCache When Using Hue + Beeswax To Run Hive Queries That Define Custom UDFs?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue, beeswax

I've set up a Hadoop cluster (using the Cloudera distro through Cloudera Manager) and I'm running some Hive queries using the Hue interface, which uses Beeswax underneath.

All my queries run fine and I have even successfully deployed a custom UDF.

But, while deploying the UDF, I ran into a very frustrating versioning issue. In the initial version of my UDF class, I used a 3rd party class that was causing a `StackOverflowError`.

I fixed this error and then verified that the UDF can be deployed and used successfully from the hive command line.

Then, when I went back to using Hue and Beeswax again, I kept getting the same error. I could fix this only by changing my UDF java class name. (From `Lower` to `Lower2`).

**Now, my question is**, what is the proper way to deal with these kind of version issues?

From what I understand, when I add jars using the handy form fields to the left, they get added to the distributed cache. So, how do I refresh/clear the distributed cache? (I couldn't get `LIST JARS;` etc. to run from within Hive / Beeswax. It gives me a syntax error.)

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: You might consider filing a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Since the classes are loaded onto the Beeswax Server JVM (same goes with HiveServer1 and HiveServer2 JVMs), deploying a new version of a jar could often require restarting these service to avoid such class loading issues.